# como remover um append

Tags: javascript, jquery

gostaria de saber como faço para remover somente o `append` que foi desmarcado pelo `checkbox`, pois em meu código quando eu seleciono um determinado`checkbox` ele adiciona um `append` de uma `img` e quando eu clicar novamente nele ele remove este `append`, porem se eu adicionar varios `append` quando eu for desmarcar um `checkbox` independente de onde eu clicar pra desmarcar ele remove todos os `append` que foram adicionados, eu gostaria que remove-se somente o que foi clicado alguém poderia me ajudar?

código:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
            var checkk = $(this).val();

            if(checkk == "nao-checado"){
                // adiciona o value de checado e adiciona o append

                $(this).val("checado");
                if($(this.checked)){
                $(this).closest('.hovereffect').find('.abcd').append('<img id="hea" class="img-responsive" src="../images/heart.png">');
                return;
              }

            }else{
                // se ja estiver checado eu removo o valor quando clicado novamente e volto ao valor padrao
                $(this).val("nao-checado");
                $(".hovereffect img:last-child").remove();

            }



        });
```

codigo html:

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
              <div class="hovereffect">
                <span class="abcd"></span>
                  <img id="he" class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/350x200" alt="">
                  <div class="overlay">
                     <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                        <label class="btn btn-primary cke">
                          <input type="checkbox" value="nao"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i>
                        </label>
                     </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
              <div class="hovereffect">
                  <span class="abcd"></span>
                  <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/350x200" alt="">
                  <div class="overlay">
                     <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                        <label class="btn btn-primary cke">
                          <input type="checkbox" value="nao"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i>
                        </label>
                     </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
              <div class="hovereffect">
                  <span class="abcd"></span>
                  <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/350x200" alt="">
                  <div class="overlay">
                     <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                        <label class="btn btn-primary cke">
                          <input type="checkbox" value="nao"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i>
                        </label>
                     </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Como esta adicionando vários elementos eles não podem ter o mesmo ID, utilize a class para identifica-los, e para remover faça a busca no mesmo parent em que foi adicionado anteriormente...

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
  var $parent = $(this).parents('.hovereffect');
  if (this.checked) {
    $('.abcd', $parent).append('<img class="hea img-responsive" src="../images/heart.png">');
  } else {
    $('.hea', $parent).remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
  <div class="hovereffect">
    <span class="abcd"></span>
    <img id="he" class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/350x200" alt="">
    <div class="overlay">
      <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-primary cke">
          <input type="checkbox" value="nao"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
  <div class="hovereffect">
    <span class="abcd"></span>
    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/350x200" alt="">
    <div class="overlay">
      <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-primary cke">
          <input type="checkbox" value="nao"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
  <div class="hovereffect">
    <span class="abcd"></span>
    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/350x200" alt="">
    <div class="overlay">
      <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-primary cke">
          <input type="checkbox" value="nao"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: quando tento implementar esse trecho de codigo ele comeca a remover como se fosse uma fila nao importa onde eu clique no checkbox ele remove sempre o primeiro depois o segundo e assim sucessivamente

Comment: @LeonardoCosta como você não incluiu um trecho de html com suas checkboxes não consegui determinar como é sua estrutura, é provável que o `.index()` esteja ficando 0 (zero) em todas elas, então você precisa utilizar outra forma de relacionar o elemento criado com o checkbox. cole na sua pergunta um trecho de html com pelo menos 3 checkboxes.

Comment: adicionei o trecho em html

Comment: @LeonardoCosta a resposta foi editada...

Comment: obrigado agora funcionou